# How to test if an ember component is missing a parameter?

Tags: ember.js

We have a button component that looks like this in our handlebars file.

```
{{some-button link="goes-to-here"}}
```

It's essentially like `{{#link-to}}` except it does a little bit more. We recently found a button on our site that was broken because it was missing the `link` parameter. I was wondering if there was a way to test or enforce that our `link` parameter is always filled out. I'm not sure off-hand how to test this though or if it is possible.

**Full Code**

**component.js**

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
});
```

**component.hbs**

```
<div class="row c2a mt50px">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    {{#link-to "contact" link class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" }}{{this.buttonText}}{{/link-to}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use a computed property for the required property and have it contain an [assert](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.7/functions/@ember%2Fdebug/assert), this will make it error out whenever the property is not overwritten and asserts are stripped away from production builds.

Comment: @Patsy Issa. I think that would work. Need to try and implement it though. Thanks!

Comment: @PatsyIssa, I like using an assert, but I can't seem to have it work using a computed property. I'm not perfectly sure why though. I posted full code above. But I ended up getting it to work simply using `didReceiveAttrs()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work by using asserts as @PatsyIssa mentioned, but also with the didReceiveAttrs.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { assert } from '@ember/debug';

export default Component.extend({
  buttonText: 'REQUEST A SAMPLE',
  didReceiveAttrs() {
    assert('Component must contain link of some kind', this.link != null);
  },
});
```

I like using `didReceiveAttrs` versus some other function like `didRender` because I believe the first is only called once on initial render.